# convert multipage pdf file to tiff single image in python

Tags: python-3.x, tiff

I have tried pdf2image and PIL to convert pdf to tiff image

when i convert pdf to tiff image for each pdf page generate new tiff image.

I want to single tiff image instead of different one.